# How to deleting image inside autogenerated picturebox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to deleting image inside picturebox ( its autogenerated) that selected mouse click, So I can delete it with delete key or maybe contextmenu...

Here the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 string theimage = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"allimages";
 string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(theimage, "*.png");
                int aa;
                for (aa = 1; aa < images.Count(); aa++)
                {
                    PictureBox myPicBox = new PictureBox();
                    myPicBox.Location = new Point(7, 240);
                    myPicBox.Width = 100;
                    myPicBox.Height = 77;
                    myPicBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                    myPicBox.Margin = new Padding(3, 3, 3, 3);
                    myPicBox.Visible = true;
                    myPicBox.Image = new Bitmap(images[aa]);
                    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(myPicBox);
                    //myPicBox.Click += new EventHandler(curPb_Click);
                    //myPicBox.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(myPicBox_MouseUp);
                    myPicBox.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(myPicBox_MouseDown);
                    myPicBox.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(mmm_Leave);
                }


        }
        //private PictureBox senderAsPictureBox = null;
        private void mmm_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox senderAsPictureBox = sender as PictureBox;
            senderAsPictureBox.BackColor = Color.Empty;
        }
        private void myPicBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox senderAsPictureBox = sender as PictureBox;
            MessageBox.Show(senderAsPictureBox.ToString());
            senderAsPictureBox.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        }
```

Here what I want to do

[image]

LOGIC:

> User selecting image thumb inside picturebox -> When USER press [delete] keys -> delete the selected image

Comment: Please state the error or issue that you are having or experiencing what is the file path when you debug this line string theimage = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"allimages";

Comment: @DJKRAZE

nope, its doesnt error at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get your problem.
If you want to clear it use this:

```
senderAsPictureBox.Image = null;
senderAsPictureBox.Invalidate();
```

EDIT:
After you set the image, set the name of the control to the imagepath:

```
                myPicBox.Name = images[aa].ToString();
```

Also create a new Eventhandler to handle your KeyDownEvent

```
     myPicBox.PreviewKeyDown += new reviewKeyDownEventHandler(myPicBox_PreviewKeyDown);
```

With this method:

```
void myPicBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox senderAsPictureBox = sender as PictureBox;
    File.Delete(senderAsPictureBox.Name);
}
```

In your MouseDownHandlerMethod focus your control with:
            senderAsPictureBox.Focus();

Comment: myPicBox.Image = new Bitmap(images[aa]); ... I want select this and delete it with delete keystroke

Comment: @radiaku are you trying to emulate a `Mouse Button Click` why do you want to do that..? if you are deleting the myPicBox.Image then there is no need to have a Mouse Click.. your Logic makes no sense. Please explain what it is you are truly trying to do

Comment: @DJKRAZE

I want to selecting image first, then catch keystroke to deleting thatcurrent selected image

Comment: why would you want to select it.. then delete it..? I you are not making any sense I can't follow what it is you need.. perhaps you could depict that with a screen shot showing what you are trying to do.. sorry I can't understand you

Comment: So you want to erase data?

Comment: @SubNatural

If you mean about imagefile, yes :)

Comment: So you have to use System.IO (using System.IO;) After that you can delete files with the method: File.Delete(path_to_image);

Comment: @SubNatural

how to getting path of image that loaded into picturebox?

Comment: Radiaku, you should already have the File Path of the Image you are already getting `string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(theimage, "*.png");` the `theimage` variable based on the index, look at the selected one in the debugger, and look for the file path..

Comment: @DJKRAZE

And how I get it when its already loaded into picturebox?

Comment: question.. do you know how to use the debugger..? if you have Directory.GetFiles already.. you can store the file path in a variable and in the for loop you pass the filepath + the name of the file .. does that make since radiaku

Comment: these 2 lines of code
`string theimage = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"allimages";
 string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(theimage, "*.png");` if you don't understand the code then who wrote it and or where did you get if from.. you are asking a question that in my opinion you already have the answer.. I am happy to help you but if you don't understand what it is that you have already then something is seriously wrong here respectfully speaking ...

Comment: Check my edit, I may have a solution. Of course not the best one

Comment: @SubNatural

Your method is complete me... :D. Accepted for answers.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Found solution from here [Get Picturebox Path](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/cc490738-6626-4065-bdec-ebadfc0d5a90) and SubNatural answers

So, I'll leave the code here for who may need it

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 string theimage = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"allimages";
 string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(theimage, "*.png");
                int aa;
                  for (aa = 1; aa < images.Count(); aa++)
            {
                PictureBox myPicBox = new PictureBox();
                myPicBox.Location = new Point(7, 240);
                myPicBox.Width = 100;
                myPicBox.Height = 77;
                myPicBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                myPicBox.Margin = new Padding(3, 3, 3, 3);
                myPicBox.Visible = true;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(images[aa], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                myPicBox.Image = Image.FromStream(fs);
                myPicBox.Name = images[aa];
                fs.Close();
                this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(myPicBox);
                //myPicBox.Click += new EventHandler(curPb_Click);
                //myPicBox.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(myPicBox_MouseUp);
                myPicBox.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(myPicBox_MouseDown);
                myPicBox.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(mmm_Leave);
                myPicBox.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(myPicBox_PreviewKeyDown);

            }


        }
        private void myPicBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox senderAsPictureBox = sender as PictureBox;
        senderAsPictureBox.Focus(); // binding for clicking
        senderAsPictureBox.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    }
    void myPicBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox senderAsPictureBox = sender as PictureBox;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            senderAsPictureBox.Image = null;
            senderAsPictureBox.Invalidate();
            senderAsPictureBox.Dispose();
            File.Delete(senderAsPictureBox.Name);
    }
```

Thanks for everyone for helping me... :) especially for @SubNatural